# PyTorch: Running unseen text through generated model

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, label, pytorch, classification

I am trying to implement a PyTorch project, found [here](https://github.com/prafulla77/Discourse_Profiling/blob/master/code/main.py).

```
import os
from process_file import process_doc
import random
import torch
torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False
import numpy as np
from argparse import ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter, ArgumentParser
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix
from full_model import Classifier
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import time


def get_batch(doc, ref_type='headline'):
    sent, ls, out, sids = [], [], [], []
    sent.append(doc.headline)
    ls.append(len(doc.headline))
    for sid in doc.sentences:
        if SPEECH:
            out.append(out_map[doc.sent_to_speech.get(sid, 'NA')])
        else:
            out.append(out_map[doc.sent_to_event.get(sid)])
        sent.append(doc.sentences[sid])
        ls.append(len(doc.sentences[sid]))
        sids.append(sid)
    ls = torch.LongTensor(ls)
    out = torch.LongTensor(out)
    return sent, ls, out, sids


def train(epoch, data):
    start_time = time.time()
    total_loss = 0
    global prev_best_macro

    for ind, doc in enumerate(data):
        model.train()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        sent, ls, out, _ = get_batch(doc)
        if has_cuda:
            ls = ls.cuda()
            out = out.cuda()

        _output, _, _, _ = model.forward(sent, ls)
        loss = criterion(_output, out)
        total_loss += loss.item()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        del sent, ls, out
        if has_cuda:
            torch.cuda.empty_cache()

    print("--Training--\nEpoch: ", epoch, "Loss: ", total_loss, "Time Elapsed: ", time.time()-start_time)
    perf = evaluate(validate_data)
    # print(perf)
    if prev_best_macro < perf:
        prev_best_macro = perf
        print ("-------------------Test start-----------------------")
        _ = evaluate(test_data, True)
        print ("-------------------Test end-----------------------")
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'discourse_lstm_model.pt')


def evaluate(data, is_test=False):
    y_true, y_pred = [], []
    model.eval()
    for doc in data:
        sent, ls, out, sids = get_batch(doc)
        if has_cuda:
            ls = ls.cuda()
            #out = out.cuda()

        _output, _, _, _ = model.forward(sent, ls)
        _output = _output.squeeze()
        _, predict = torch.max(_output, 1)
        y_pred += list(predict.cpu().numpy() if has_cuda else predict.numpy())
        temp_true = list(out.numpy())
        y_true += temp_true

    print("MACRO: ", precision_recall_fscore_support(y_true, y_pred, average='macro'))
    print("MICRO: ", precision_recall_fscore_support(y_true, y_pred, average='micro'))
    if is_test:
        print("Classification Report \n", classification_report(y_true, y_pred))
    print("Confusion Matrix \n", confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred))
    return precision_recall_fscore_support(y_true, y_pred, average='macro')[2]


if __name__ == '__main__':

    parser = ArgumentParser(formatter_class=ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
    # parser.add_argument('--drop', help='DROP', default=6, type=float)
    # parser.add_argument('--learn_rate', help='LEARNING RATE', default=0, type=float)
    # parser.add_argument('--loss_wt', help='LOSS WEIGHTS', default=0, type=str)
    parser.add_argument('--seed', help='SEED', default=0, type=int)

    args = parser.parse_args()

    has_cuda = torch.cuda.is_available()

    SPEECH = 0
    if SPEECH:
        out_map = {'NA':0, 'Speech':1}
    else:
        out_map = {'NA':0,'Main':1,'Main_Consequence':2, 'Cause_Specific':3, 'Cause_General':4, 'Distant_Historical':5,
        'Distant_Anecdotal':6, 'Distant_Evaluation':7, 'Distant_Expectations_Consequences':8}

    train_data = []
    validate_data = []
    test_data = []
    for domain in ["Business", "Politics", "Crime", "Disaster", "kbp"]:
        subdir = "../data/train/"+domain
        files = os.listdir(subdir)
        for file in files:
            if '.txt' in file:
                doc = process_doc(os.path.join(subdir, file), domain) #'../data/Business/nyt_corpus_data_2007_04_27_1843240.txt'
                #print(doc.sent_to_event)
                train_data.append(doc)
        subdir = "../data/test/"+domain
        files = os.listdir(subdir)
        for file in files:
            if '.txt' in file:
                doc = process_doc(os.path.join(subdir, file), domain) #'../data/Business/nyt_corpus_data_2007_04_27_1843240.txt'
                #print(doc.sent_to_event)
                test_data.append(doc)


    subdir = "../data/validation"
    files = os.listdir(subdir)
    for file in files:
        if '.txt' in file:
            doc = process_doc(os.path.join(subdir, file), 'VAL') #'../data/Business/nyt_corpus_data_2007_04_27_1843240.txt'
            #print(doc.sent_to_event)
            validate_data.append(doc)
    print(len(train_data), len(validate_data), len(test_data))

    seed = args.seed
    np.random.seed(seed)
    torch.manual_seed(seed)
    if has_cuda:
        torch.cuda.manual_seed(seed)
    random.seed(seed)
    np.random.seed(seed)

    prev_best_macro = 0.

    model = Classifier({'num_layers': 1, 'hidden_dim': 512, 'bidirectional': True, 'embedding_dim': 1024,
                        'dropout': 0.5, 'out_dim': len(out_map)})

    if has_cuda:
        model = model.cuda()
    model.init_weights()

    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

    print("Model Created")

    params = filter(lambda p: p.requires_grad, model.parameters())
    optimizer = optim.Adam(params, lr=5e-5, betas=[0.9, 0.999], eps=1e-8, weight_decay=0)

    try:
        for epoch in range(15):
            print("---------------------------Started Training Epoch = {0}--------------------------".format(epoch+1))
            train(epoch, train_data)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print ("----------------- INTERRUPTED -----------------")
        evaluate(validate_data)
        evaluate(test_data)
```

Running this code, I have successfully outputted a .pt model trained on a corpus of ~400 articles, each article annotated according to its sectional content (data from the Github repo).

Now, I want to annotate a new, unseen article using this model, but I can't quite figure out how to do so. I have a feeling the classification code is already implemented in the snippet above and I'd really appreciate any help/guidance as to how I could go about classifying an unseen article using this code. Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Just change `subdir = "../data/validation"` to the folder your article is. Notice the article must be a `.txt`.

Comment: Also, please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

Well, your code does training and testing already. You just need an extra piece of code that loads the trained model and test data for inference.

It should be something like that:

```
# load trained model:
model = Classifier({'num_layers': 1, 'hidden_dim': 512, 'bidirectional': True, 'embedding_dim': 1024,
                        'dropout': 0.5, 'out_dim': len(out_map)})

model.load_state_dict(torch.load("PATH/TO/SAVED/MODEL.pt")

# load data:
subdir = "PATH/TO/DOCS/"
files = os.listdir(subdir)
validate_data = []
for file in files:
    if '.txt' in file:
        doc = process_doc(os.path.join(subdir, file), 'VAL') 
        validate_data.append(doc)
print(len(train_data), len(validate_data), len(test_data))

# use the evaluate function with is_test=True for inference.
evaluate(data, is_test=True)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Just to clarify, where is this code inserted into the snippet above / how do I alter the above code to incorporate your snippet?

Comment: You should integrate it in your code! How to do it is a design choice of yours.

Comment: You can add those extra lines under `if __name__ == '__main__'`. You can use the `arg_parse` to select the inference mode from the command line.

Comment: Thanks once more! I was able to successfully implement this by removing the try/except training block and appending your code to '\_\_main\_\_'. However, the script still requires that I manually provide an annotation file alongside a new article.txt (it did not create its own annotations). I'm hoping to get the script to annotate/classify a file it's never seen before. Currently, it's outputting a Classification Report (precision    recall  f1-score   support) and a Confusion Matrix.

Comment: 1) If yous set `is_test=False`, then you should not have this problem. 2) At StackOverflow, we are happy to help you with coding problems. But You cannot ask us to do the coding part for you. Please spend some time understanding your codebase before making `what-should-I-do-here?` type of questions.

Comment: If I set is_test=False, then process_file.py fails because it depends on the presence of a .ann file. I apologize for the broad question. I'm very new to PyTorch and I've been tinkering with this codebase for hours with little luck.

Comment: My mistake, you indeed have to change the `evaluate()` function so it does not require an `.ann` file